# Create search item to filter the shuttle dynamically in oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, apex

Suppose that I have a huge amount of data in a shuttle and I would like to search for a specific result. Is there a way to create a page item that can help me to filter the shuttle dynamically just like the text field with auto complete item in the oracle apex?
[image: a picture for the shuttle]

Comment: Have you considered using the popup lov component instead of a shuttle ? If you're on a recent version of apex that has a good search, allows multiple values to be selected and can be rendered inline

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I used this plug in: 
https://dickdral.blogspot.com/2017/07/restricting-shuttle-choices-even-faster.html
and it helped me to achieve what I was looking for

Comment: Is this plugin for free?

Comment: Yes 100%, you can download it and use it. If you need anything I'll be happy to help you.

Comment: I appreciate the help :)